# How to add "hidden" app version info in next.js app (available in client)?

Tags: next.js, versioning

How can I (should I) add some "invisible" version info as "meta data" to my Next.js app, so that it is available from the browser ?

My goal is that it is **not regularly visible** to the user, but can be found somewhere, e.g. to confirm which version has been deployed.

I thought of these options:

- Add a `<meta version="1.2.3">`,
  but there seems to be no "valid" meta tag for a version number.
- Add a comment like `<!-- v1.2.3 -->`,
  but there seems to be no clean way to add comments in Next.js.
- Add some invisible `<div>` somewhere,
  but that seems very "hacky" / "dirty" to me.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options come to my mind:

1. Add it as a data-attribute to the root of your app, or even `<html>` or `<body>` if you like. It would look like `<html data-app-version="1.2.3">`
2. Add it in the global window object to be accessible via JS. Something like `window.appVersion = "1.2.3"

Answer (score 2):

I still didn't find a perfect solution, but here is some more information / ideas:
*(I do realize that this is essentially also just "add it to the window object", as Olavi suggested)*

1. Add the version number to the Next.js page props.
2. Add the version number to the redux store.
3. Note: There is an RFC to [add a RawHTML Component](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/129).

#### 1. Add the version number to the Next.js page props

I've added a property `appVersion` to the Next.js page props. This way I can read the version number from the browser console with:

```
window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps.appVersion
```

##### Example:

I took the version number from the package.json, and passed it over to the Next.js page props:

package.json

```
"version": "1.2.3",
```

[next.config.js:](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration)

```
const nextConfig = {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        appVersion:   process.env.npm_package_version || '',
    },
}
```

[.getStaticProps():](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { serverRuntimeConfig = {} } = getConfig() || {};

export const getStaticProps = function(){
    return {
        props: {
            appVersion: serverRuntimeConfig.appVersion || '',
        },
    };
};
```

#### 2. Add the version number to the redux store

Add the version number to the redux store, e.g. into `state.app.appVersion`,
then you can read it later from the browser console with:

```
window.__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__.getState().app.appVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

To include the version number from your `package.json` into your Next.js application, you can utilize the `next.config.js` configuration file to expose the version as an environment variable. This method ensures that only the version number is exposed to the client-side, avoiding any potential security issues with exposing the entire `package.json` file.

Here's how you can do it:

1. **Modify your** `next.config.js`: Open your `next.config.js` file at the root of your Next.js project and add the following code. This code reads the version from your `package.json` and assigns it to an environment variable named `APP_VERSION`.

```js
// next.config.js
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  env: {
    APP_VERSION: packageJson.version,
  },
};
```

2. **Access the Environment Variable in Your Application:** You can now use `process.env.APP_VERSION` to access your app version anywhere in your Next.js application. For example, you could display the version number in a component like this:

```js
// In a component, page or layout
const MyAppVersionComponent = () => {
  return <div>App Version: {process.env.APP_VERSION}</div>;
};
```

**Why Use This Method?**

- **Security:** It prevents the potential exposure of sensitive information by not importing the entire package.json directly into
  your client-side code.
- **Simplicity:** It leverages Next.js's built-in support for environment variables, making it straightforward to implement.
- **Performance:** There is no runtime overhead for fetching the version number since it's embedded in the build-time environment
  variables.

This method is ideal for when you need to display the current version of your application within the UI or use the version number for any other client-side logic in a secure and efficient manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't answer my main question: how to add "comment-like" code somewhere, that is **not regularly visible**, but can be found if you know how, e.g. using the dev-tools. I admit the headline is misleading :/ I emphasized "hidden" in my question.

Comment: Ah, you could just console log the `process.env.APP_VERSION`

Comment: I mean, when the Website is online, I'd like to be able to check in the browser which version is online. E.g. to confirm that the deployment was successful. But I don't want it visible to the user (it's ok if the user is able to find it as well, but it should not be obvious).